# Segues called from several areas not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, segue

I have a segue being called by 5 different methods when a `UIView animateWithDuration` is complete. I find that if I just call the segue once (animating just one `UIImageView`) everything works fine, but by calling multiple this error appears:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0x7ffc7b714280> on <Playing_Page: 0x7ffc7b7128b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The completion block (Same for all animations)

```
//In completion block
if (a!=b) {
    [self squareOneColour];
    [self squareOneMover];
}
if (a==b) {
    if (self.squareOne.hidden==NO) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gameOver" sender:self];
    }
}
//Conditions must be included in answer. The are unique to each animation
```

Therefore when all five animations are complete (and meet conditions) it calls the segue 5 times and creates the error (I'm pretty sure, cause I did a lot of testing)

What I want is for `Playing_Page` to transition to `GameOver` without errors when the animations (and meet conditions) are finished. Any help?

Comment: Where and when are you calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Comment: In the completion block of `squareOneMover` in `Playing_Page`. And it performs the segue *when* the animation is finished @Mitley.

Comment: I mean, in what parent method, `viewDidLoad`, `IBAction`, etc

Comment: A method that is called be a `IBAction`

Comment: Of course you get that error, because once you've called preformSegue, Playing_Page is no longer on screen, when you call it the other 4 times. You need to change your logic so you're only calling it once. It's hard to advise you on how to do that without knowing more about your 5 animations.

Comment: What's more to know? I have included the completion block and most `UIView animateWithDurations` are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can increment an integer property in the completion block of each animation, and inspect that value in the overridden setter for that property. In the following example, that property is called counter, and I had three animations that were triggered from buttons. I'm just showing the code for one button, but the code in the completion blocks is identical.

```
-(void)setCounter:(NSInteger)counter {
    _counter = counter;
    if (_counter == 3) {
        NSLog(@"All three animations are done");
        // do your segue here
    }
}

- (IBAction)leftButton:(id)sender {
    self.leftCon.constant = 300;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.counter +=1;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's amazing. Except you excluded `a` and `b`. I forgot to write in the question (sorry) that they are different for each animation. So this is why my situation is so difficult, because another if-statement splits the first one into 5 places for segues to be called

Comment: @Minestrone-Soup, Well, if you need more help, you need to edit your question to give more information, just like I asked in my comment. What do you mean by "they are different for each animation"?